# Simple Add class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I've this code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  document.getElementById('HAVEATESTHERE').className = "newClass";
}
```

I want to add a class to `#HAVEATESTHERE` in javascript, it does not work

Am I missing something ?

Comment: you code seems ok. do you want to add more than one class?

Comment: can you post the html code also ?

Comment: Do you want to override the class or add another class ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `classList.add` method:

```
document.getElementById('HAVEATESTHERE').classList.add('first','second', ... );
```

Also, please make sure you add your class after DOM is rendered.

Take into account, that `element.className = 'someClass'` will override existing classes with `someClass`.

Comment: @RayonDabre the op code sets the class name, where this adds to it? ie if it had `class1` then `.className = 'class2'` will overwrite `class1` where `classlist.add('class2')` will set the classname `'class1 class2'`. +1

Comment: In case it would already have a class - className = "newClass" will override the existing one/s.

Answer (score 1):

elementid is your element`s id and yourclass is that what class do you want add this element.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('#elementid').addclass('yourClass');
    }
```

Comment: Please add description to your answer. We are voting to delete this question because of its **length** and **content**.

Answer (score 0):

Code is fine, see this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/L5e0j43s/)

Ensure that it is either

- Added in the `window.onload` section

  ```
   window.onload = function(){

       document.getElementById('HAVEATESTHERE').className = "class1";

   };
  ```

if there are already some classes for this element (as suggested by your updated OP), then use [classlist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add a new class to that list

```
     document.getElementById('HAVEATESTHERE').classList.add("class1");
```

-  Or the script section is added at the end of body after all the markup is already loaded.

Comment: By the way I put this line into jQuery(document).ready(function($) {}); because I wrote Jquery into this file too

Comment: can you share a fiddle or make changes in the fiddle I have posted?

Comment: @CorentinBranquet your syntax was incorrect, check this updated one https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/efyy0w3u/1/

Answer (score 0):

make sure you don't have duplicate IDs for divs. Check this:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").className = "myclass";
}
```

```css
.myclass {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.mystyle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: coral;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a class for div.</p>

<div id="myDIV">
Sample div
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Class</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to mix JavaScript inside jQuery function. Please take care of that. And if you are only using jquery then please use your code

As in this formate

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#HAVEATESTHERE').addclass('newClass');
}
```

use addclass() function to add class to your div.

with simple js please try to use anonymous function like this

```
(function(){
  var d = document.getElementById("HAVEATESTHERE");
  d.className = " newClass";
})();
```